# I want to open the alert window

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

I want to confirm box before calling the delete method.
and open the alert window How do I modify the following sources?

jsp page(delete box click) ==> delete method ==>Date Base ==> JSP(onload)

=================================================================

```
@RequestMapping(value="delete.do")
    public String delete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap modelmap) throws Exception{
       String url = "";
       try{
          int idx = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idx")); 
          int commentCnt = boardService.delCheck(idx);
          if(commentCnt == 0){
              boardService.delete(idx);
              url = "redirect:board_list.do";
          }else{
              modelmap.addAttribute("errCode", 1);
              url = "redirect:content.do?idx="+idx;
          }
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return url;
   }



   JSP PAGE
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function deleteCheck(){
                var errCode = ${errCode};
                if(errCode != null || errCode != "")
                {
                    alert("alert");
                }
            }
        </script>

<body onload="deleteCheck()">

<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteCheck(){
   var errCode = ${errCode};
      if(errCode != null || errCode != "")
       {
          var choice = confirm("are you sure you want to delete");
          if(choice){
            //proceed with deletion
          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thank answers.
However, this should not be executed.

Comment: Did you mean that if the user selects `yes`, deletion should not be executed..?

Comment: Click Delete, and just want the alert window will.

Comment: isn't the current code showing an alert *"alert"*? sorry, i didn't understand your problem

Comment: Looking over the source. 
Java code: modelmap.addAttribute ("errCode", 1); 
Takes the value passed to the JSP PAGE. 
running an onload jsp page. 
I want to open the alert window. 
Do you understand me?